# ASP.net sizing one object as a percent of the page minus the size of another object

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a page with multiple possible banners and a silverlight app below it. I want to size the silverlight app so that it's height is always 100% of the available screen height minus the height of the banner so that there are never any scroll bars on the page. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is really more a CSS+HTML question than one for ASP.NET. Can you give a little more info about this? What web browsers are you supporting? Are you currently using any CSS+HTML frameworks already?

Comment: I need to support IE8, IE9, and Firefox. Not sure what you mean by CSS+HTML framework, but I'm not using an CSS on the page as the page consists of only the two elements mentioned.

Comment: I was thinking maybe there was a method of getting the total pixels available in a window, and then getting the actual height of my banner object, subtract the two and use that for the height of my silverlight app. Is there no way to get these two values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scnWid,scnHei;
if (self.innerHeight) // all except Explorer
{
    scnWid = self.innerWidth;
    scnHei = self.innerHeight;
}
else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
{
    scnWid = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    scnHei = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
else if (document.body) // other Explorers
{
    scnWid = document.body.clientWidth;
    scnHei = document.body.clientHeight;
}

var SilverLightAppHeight = scnHei - /* insert banner height here */;
</script>
```

then later when you want to set your form size

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('silverlightform').style.height = SilverLightAppHeight;
</script>
```

Comment: is this code that would go in an .aspx page? I need asp code to accomplish this.

Comment: this is javascript code and would go in a script tag, I will look for an update with asp

Comment: oh ok, so how would I call this code? I have another function with a line of code in it like document.getElementById('silverlightform').style.height = '100%';

How would I go about replacing the 100% with a call to your code?